# php Alert when date is near

Tags: php, wordpress

i use WordPress to build a site.i need to get an alert to my web site profile page when a registration date is near.i use an available database to get the date and its saved as a string.and i check it with current date this is the code i tried. my problem is the format is not converted to the date still when i var_dump it.any help would be great!

```
global $wpdb;
$id=(int)$user_ID;
$FinalDay = $wpdb->get_var( "my query" );//this works!
//$Final day is the string i try to convert 
$FinalDay= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($FinalDay));
$now = new DateTime();
echo var_dump($FinalDay);//but it gives me a string formated one!
$interval = $now->diff($FinalDay);
if ( $FinalDay > $now ) {
  echo "<p>Expiry date is {$FinalDay}</p>";
  echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
}
else {
  echo 'Licence Expired';
}
```

Comment: `date(format, timestamp)` is a function to format it explicitly, if you only want the timestamp just use `strtotime($FinalDay)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use DateTime class.

Change

```
$FinalDay= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($FinalDay));
```

With

```
$FinalDay= DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $FinalDay);
```

$FinalDay should be in format 'Y-m-d H:i:s'.

Comment: or if you dont know the format and try to keep the existing code use `$FinalDay= new DateTime($FinalDay);` which is more or less what `strtotime()` does in the first place

Comment: @Rosh_LK was your problem managed? or do you have any questions?